# OpenLayers 3 Map Bounds

Tags: openlayers

I have been using Leaflet.js but since I wanted the webgl performance I switched to the newly OpenLayers 3 which seems awesome.

I had bounds on my Leaflet.js Map:

```
var sw = L.latLng(-90, 180),
    ne = L.latLng(90, -180),
    maxBounds = L.latLngBounds(sw, ne);

map = new L.Map('map', {            
        attribution: "",
        attributionControl: false,
        maxBounds: maxBounds,
        zoomControl: false,
        zoomAnimation: true
    }
);
```

where I only had a single projection being allowed to be displayed and if the user would attempt to go out of bounds, the map would bounce back with an animation.

Is there a way to have something similar with OpenLayers 3?

I basically want to prevent dragging or changing center beyond the actual bounds of a single projection.

I used the following code with OpenLayers 3:

```
map.on('postrender', function () {
    var view = map.getView(),
        worldExtent = view.getProjection().getExtent(),
        extent = view.calculateExtent(map.getSize());

    if (!ol.extent.containsExtent(worldExtent, extent)) {
        var newExtent = ol.extent.getIntersection(extent, restrictedExtent);
        view.fit(newExtent, map.getSize());
    }
});
```

which displays a signle projection all right but I can drag or move the center out of it.

Comment: I would explore attaching an event listener..for a 'moveend' and then call a custom function that does the quick check and if it's bad, issue a pan to the nearest legal spot. see example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/moveend.html

Comment: this is what i had in mind actually but i wnated to know if OL3 had something out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the extent when initialising your view. Within docs ([link](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.View.html)) it sais:

The extent that constrains the center, in other words, center cannot be set outside this extent. Default is undefined.

consider this

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-6655.5402445057125, 6709968.258934638],
    extent:[-16655.5402445057125, 6609968.258934638,0,6809968],
    zoom: 13
  })
});
```

You have to consider also the zoom levels available. If a high zoom level is available then your map will be displayed ouside the supplied extend but your map center wont go over the supplied extent.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/708mhsfy/) to test.